# How to update the Google Cloud scheduler with Python api

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to update google scheduler job.But,it does not work well.How do I this?
Now I understand what problem is.The problem is that the option class is wrong.
How should I write this place?

**Target(topic_name="projects/aaa/topics/bbb",data="test".encode("utf-8"))**

The error message.

> TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected google.cloud.scheduler.v1.PubsubTarget got PubsubTarget.

my code

```
import os
from google.cloud import scheduler_v1
from google.cloud.scheduler_v1 import PubsubTarget as Target

from google.protobuf import field_mask_pb2

pub = Target(topic_name="projects/aaa/topics/bbb",data="test".encode("utf-8"))

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = './test.json'
client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient()
job = { 'name': "projects/aaa/locations/us-central1/jobs/test",
       "description": "c",
       "schedule": "59 * * * *",
       "pubsub_target":pub
        }
update_mask = field_mask_pb2.FieldMask(paths=['description','schedule','pubsub_target'])

response = client.update_job(job=job,update_mask=update_mask)
print(response)
```

Comment: Did you try to replace `Target` by `google.cloud.scheduler_v1.PubsubTarget`?

Comment: Can you also share the version of your dependency?

Comment: Could you please share your requirements.txt file?

Comment: Yes,I replaced "Target" to "google.cloud.scheduler_v1.PubsubTarget".But,the same error showed.

Comment: My dependency is as below

`astroid==2.4.2
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
boto3==1.15.15
botocore==1.18.15
cachetools==4.1.1
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi==1.14.3
chardet==3.0.4
google-api-core==1.22.2
google-api-python-client==1.12.5
google-auth==1.21.3
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.4
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-cloud-core==1.4.1
google-cloud-scheduler==2.0.0
google-cloud-storage==1.31.2
google-crc32c==1.0.0
google-resumable-media==1.0.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
grpcio==1.33.1
httplib2==0.18.1
idna==2.10
isort==5.4.2
jmespath==0.10.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3`

Comment: `libcst==0.3.13
mccabe==0.6.1
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.1.0
proto-plus==1.11.0
protobuf==3.13.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
pylint==2.6.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-firebase==1.2
pytz==2020.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.24.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.6
s3transfer==0.3.3
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
toml==0.10.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
typing-inspect==0.6.0
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.25.10
wrapt==1.12.1`

Answer (score 0):

```
   import os
   from google.cloud import scheduler_v1
   from google.cloud.scheduler_v1 import PubsubTarget as Target



   os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = './test.json'
   client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient()

   job = Job()
   job.name = 'projects/aaa/locations/us-central1/jobs/test'
   job.description = 'c'
   job.schedule = '59 * * * *'
   job.time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles'
   pt = Target()
   pt.topic_name = 'projects/aaa/topics/bbb'
   pt.data = 'test'.encode('utf-8')
   job.pubsub_target = pt
   job = client.create_job(parent='projects/aaa/locations/us-central1', job=job)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).